# Returning 2d dynamic array from a fucntion (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, matrix, return

first i have to let you know i'm a newbie self-learner .. all i know about c++ comes from websites, books and videos
A problem requires me to make a matrices calculator using 2d dynamic arrays 
actually I'm very confused about pointers X( ... i just hate it i can't fully understand its logic ...
i wrote a long-like code with many dynamic 2d arrays .. still confusing me !
the program is supposed to perform addition and evaluate the determinant for each matrix.
here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//DECLARING PROTOTYPES
int **addMat(int **matrix1, int **matrix2, int rows1, int columns1, int rows2, int   columns2);

int main()
{
int **matrix1, **matrix2, rows1, columns1, rows2, columns2;
cout<<"Please enter first matrix rows and columns numbers: ";
cin>>rows1>>columns1;
cout<<"Please enter second matrix rows and columns numbers: ";
cin>>rows2>>columns2;

matrix1 = new int *[rows1];
for (int i=0; i<rows1; i++)
{
    matrix1[i] = new int [columns1];
}

matrix2 = new int *[rows2];
for (int j=0; j<rows2; j++)
{
    matrix2[j] = new int [columns2];
}

//LOADING MATRICES
cout<<"Please enter first matrix elements: ";
for (int r1=0; r1<rows1; r1++)
{
    for (int c1=0; c1<columns1; c1++)
    {
        cin>>matrix1[r1][c1];
    }
}

cout<<"Please enter second matrix elements: ";
for (int r2=0; r2<rows2; r2++)
{
    for (int c2=0; c2<columns2; c2++)
    {
        cin>>matrix2[r2][c2];
    }
}
int **addit;
addit = addMat(matrix1,matrix2,rows1,columns1,rows2,columns2);
if (addit!=NULL)
{
for(int i=0; i<rows1; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<columns1; j++)
        cout<<addit[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
}
return 0;
}


int **addMat(int **matrix1, int **matrix2, int rows1, int columns1, int rows2, int   columns2)
{
if ((rows1!=rows2) && (columns1!=columns2))
{
    cout<<"The Two Matrices Are Not Of The Same Size. Cannot Perform Addition\n";
    return NULL;
}
else
{   int **Addthis=0;
    Addthis = new int *[rows1];
    for (int add=0; add<rows1; add++)
    {
        Addthis[add] = new int [columns1];
    }


    for (int i=0; i<rows1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<columns1; j++)
            Addthis[i][j]=(matrix1[i][j])+(matrix2[i][j]);
    }
    return Addthis;

    }
    }
```

i know this so inefficient ... and i didn't write the determinant part yet
because i got stuck here
what confuses me more is the way i return the 2d array to the main function !

the program fails when:

1. it perform the function even number of columns 1 not equal columns 2
   ( but rows are the same ) and returns garbage !
2. if rows and columns of both matrices are not equal, it shows the
       message  "The Two Matrices Are Not Of The Same Size. Cannot Perform
       Addition ", but then the program crashes and the windows shows an
       error msg " the program has stopped working "

i'm just too confused and disappointed about this 
any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Your matrices should be implemented as a class that contains the 2d array and row/column counts. They should then expose member functions for performing all linear algebra. Your implementation is in C and not taking advantage of any of the encapsulation available in C++

Comment: This test `((rows1!=rows2) && (columns1!=columns2))` should be `(rows1 != rows2 || columns1 != columns2)`. If either doesn't match, you can't perform your addition.

Comment: @cppguy I believe the language is called "C with cout".

Comment: @ooga ops ! i missed that ! thanks for pointing out 
that's one of my problems solved

Comment: @ooga IRONIC .. but correcting the condition solved both problems :D 
thanks again

Comment: @cppguy bro, i actually mentioned that i'm a newbie i still don't learn anything about classes
i'm currently learning Data structure :(
i believe u're answer would help if i know how to use classes
but anyways thanks for taking the time to reply